# JavaFX Column sorting for a Column<V, T> where T extends ObservableList<U>

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a table in which I'm displaying email addresses for a set of clients, such that when they have one email address it displays, if there is a list, it states in the table cell the number of email addresses they have, and if they have none, it displays "None". This all works fine, I have simply set up the table cell to take care of this. However, the column does not sort in a reasonable order, which is fair enough, given that it's trying to sort on a list, so I thought I would set a custom comparator on the column thus:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public static <T extends ObservableList<U>, V extends Entity, U extends Entity> void initializeFilteredStringEntityListColumn(
        GridColumn<V, T> column,
        Function<V, T> propertyProvider,
        Function<U, String> stringProvider,
        String pluralName,
        ListFilterProperty<V> filters) {
    column.setCellFactory(col -> new StringListTableCell(stringProvider, pluralName));
    column.setComparator(new Comparator<T>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(T list1, T list2) {
            U firstItemList1 = list1.isEmpty() ? null : list1.get(0);
            U firstItemList2 = list2.isEmpty() ? null : list2.get(0);
            String listOneComparative = stringProvider.apply(firstItemList1);
            String listTwoComparative = stringProvider.apply(firstItemList2);
            int compareTo = listOneComparative.compareTo(listTwoComparative);                
            return compareTo;
        }
    });
    column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        V value = cellData.getValue();
        T t = propertyProvider.apply(value);
        return (ObservableValue<T>) t;
    });
    column.setFilterContextMenu(SearchFilterContextMenu.contains(filters));
}
```

When debugging it definitely steps into the compare method, but the table doesn't seem to apply the sort order. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: Ah, this was caused by a couple of NPEs in the compare method. I'll leave this here in case it helps anyone else as stupid as me: 
`String listOneComparative = firstItemList1 == null ? "" : stringProvider.apply(firstItemList1);
                String listTwoComparative = firstItemList2 == null ? "" : stringProvider.apply(firstItemList2);
                int compareTo = listOneComparative.compareTo(listTwoComparative);`

Comment: You can self-answer the question if you think it may be helpful to others. After some grace period you can then accept the answer. This will make it easier for other users to find than answering it in a comment.